Disturbance error transfer function
I was trying to solve some examples from the book Feedback Control of Dynamic Systems by Franklin, Powell & Emami-Naemi. (Seventh Edition, Pages 195 & 204) about PID controllers. The problem is asking to determine the system type and steady-state error properties with respect to disturbance inputs when Dc(s) = Kp. This is the system and the solution the book shows

I got the same steady error and systems type, however, I didn't get the same transfer function or the constant so I don't understand why it is different. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? Please.
This is how I figured it out


Here is where you went wrong : 
Here is what i found out: \$ Y =  \frac{A}{s(\tau \cdot s + 1)} [-Y \cdot h \cdot k_p + \frac{B}{A} \cdot W] \iff T(1+\frac{A h k_p}{s(\tau s +1)}) = \frac{B}{s(\tau s +1)}\$
Thus:  \$ T = \frac{Y}{W} = \frac{-E}{W} = -\frac{B}{s(\tau s+1) + A h k_p}\$

What I understand of the last expression you talked about is that it is true when the feedback is unitary. In this case, wouldn't the block -h make false that statement because it is between the signal output Y and the error E? If I analyze the transfer function between W and the output Y, then -h would be in the feedback path, and not in the forward path as I showed there. For me that block changes the expression of the numerator of the transfer function, I don't know if my analysis is right or if there is something I am missing.

The way you recreated the closed loop is false. @ylr

Can you explain to me which part is wrong? Please

I thought i pointed out at the screenshot in my answer ?

I'm sorry if I'm too pushy, but it still doesn't make sense to me your expression there: when the system does not have unity feedback, then the output of the summing junction (the error) is not the difference between the reference input and the actual output. That changes that equivalence.

Try to find the transfer function without optimizing/reconstructing the scheme. @ylr
